# change li ordered list to be select

Tags: html

I have this HTML Menu:

```
<div id="CustomerMenu">
<ul>
<li><a href="/my-integra/">Home</a></li>

<li><a href="/my-integra/?id=myaccount">Account</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/my-integra/?id=contacts">Contacts</a></li>
        <li><a href="/my-integra/?id=viewcontact&seq=<?php echo $_SESSION["integra-uk.net"]["contact"]; ?>">My Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="/my-integra/?id=myaccount">Company Details</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="/my-integra/?id=billing">Billing</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/my-integra/?id=invoices">Invoices</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="/my-integra/?id=tickets">Tickets</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/my-integra/?id=openticket">Open Ticket</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<?php
if($SettingsCustomer["reseller"] == 'Y') {
    echo '<li><a href="/my-integra/?id=reseller_customers">My Customers</a></li>';
}
?>

<li><a href="/my-integra/?id=logout">Logout</a>
</ul>
</div>
```

how can i change this using media queries in CSS to show a select element when the screen size gets to a certain width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make two menu one hidden when desktop and one hidden when mobile:

Feel free to test this here: http://jsfiddle.net/uc3eLazc/1/

**CSS:**

```
// DESKTOP
    .mobile
    {
        display:none;
    }

        .desktop
    {
        display:block;
    }

// MOBILE
    @media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
        .mobile
    {
        display:block;
    }
        .desktop
    {
        display:none;
    }

    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="CustomerMenu" class="desktop">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/my-integra/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/my-integra/?id=myaccount">Account</a>
    </ul>
</div>

<select id="ListeElement" class="mobile"> 
   <option value="valeur1">Option 1</option> 
   <option value="valeur2">Option 2</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: i want to change the css menu to be a select element

Comment: check this JS Code - http://pastebin.com/mUEc9i3t - this changes it into a select element, is there any way i can put the sub items with a - next to them on the left so it shows them as sub items?

Comment: @user2710234 sorry I can't see the page from here, but yes you can with the before css3 rule http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_before

Comment: sorry, not sure i understand?

Comment: @user2710234: If you want to add a "-" before some elements, you can by using ::berore : http://jsfiddle.net/uc3eLazc/2/

Comment: did you check my JS code i put in a pastebin? this JS code changes the li list to be a select element

Comment: @user2710234 I cant' check on pastebin because of my firewall, please use jsfiddle or paste code here please :-)

Comment: @user2710234: please consider to valid my ask if it respond to your question to help other people if they have the same question. Could you put the pastbin into jsfiddle in order to help you? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply change your UL to be a SELECT menu using only media queries.

What you can do is use a plug-in like TinyNav to achieve this:

http://tinynav.viljamis.com/

The instructions are all on the page but you basically include their script, then use code like this to activate it along with calling the JS etc:

```
/* styles for desktop */
.tinynav { display: none }

/* styles for mobile */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .tinynav { display: block }
    #nav { display: none }
}
```